# Erro ao executar programa em python

Tags: python

Eu fiz esse programa em python :

```
//////////color.py

#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-




class Color(object):

    string = {
        "RED": "\x1b[31m",
        "GREEN": "\x1b[32m",
        "BLUE": "\x1b[34m",
        "YELLOW": "\x1b[33m",
        "CYAN": "\x1b[36m",
        "GREY": "\x1b[38;5;247m",
        "ENDC": "\x1b[0m"
    }

    if use_colors in ["off", "OFF"]:
        string = {
            "RED": "",
            "GREEN": "",
            "BLUE": "",
            "YELLOW": "",
            "CYAN": "",
            "GREY": "",
            "ENDC": ""
        }

//hello.py

#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from color import Color as colors

class HelloWorld(object):

    def __init__(self, colors):

           print("%s".format
           (
             self.colors.string["RED"], "Hello ", self.colors.string["ENDC"],
             self.colors.string["GREEN"], "World!"],
             self.colors.string["ENDC"])
           )
```

porem ao fazer:

```
$python hello.py
```

ele gera o seguinte erro abaixo:

> File "hello.py", line 13
>       self.colors.string["GREEN"], "World!"],
>                                            ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Qual é o erro? Pois eu testei criando uma variável chamada `msg="Hello World"`
e dá erro também.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem um colchete a mais nessa linha:

```
self.colors.string["GREEN"], "World!"],
```

Comment: Não entendi o voto negativo. O que o Gustavo falou está certo.

Comment: Deu certo aqui rodei o programa e funfou legal..